# Определить, есть ли экземпляр класса a() в списке и получить его индекс

Tags: python

Пример кода:

```
class a():
    pass:
d = [1,2,3]
for i in range(3):
    d.append(a())
print(d)
print(a in d)
```

Вывод получается:

```
[1, 2, 3, <__main__.a object at 0x00000000053ECEB8>, <__main__.a object at 
0x00000000053EC630>, <__main__.a object at 0x00000000053ECFD0>]
False
```

Как узнать, что экземпляр a() присутствует в списке?

upd: Как теперь получить индекс первого вхождения a() в d?

Comment: any(isinstance(x, a) for x in d)

Comment: Спасибо! Оказалось просто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто узнать, есть ли элемент с нужным типом в списке:

```
any(isinstance(x, a) for x in d)
```

Получить индекс такого элемента:

```
i = next(i for i, x in enumerate(d) if isinstance(x, a))
```

Если элемент с нужным типом не будет найден, то будет выброшено исключение `StopIteration`. Чтобы не выбрасывалось исключение, а возвращалось например, `None`, можно использовать второй параметр функции `next()` с нужным значением, которое будет возвращаться, если элемент не найден:

```
i = next((i for i, x in enumerate(d) if isinstance(x, a)), None)
```

См. [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

Также, модифицировав второй вариант (заменив `next` на `list` или добавив квадратные скобки) можно получить список индексов:

```
i = list(i for i, x in enumerate(d) if isinstance(x, a))
# или i = [i for i, x in enumerate(d) if isinstance(x, a)]
```